# printing emojis on images using jimp

Tags: javascript, node.js, jimp

I am trying to print emojis, let's say  using `.print()` onto images with `jimp` but when `.write()` the image the emojis show up as `??`.

Is there a way to print emojis on images using `jimp`?

Comment: `.print` is for printing text onto an image, from a bitmap font which you have loaded. You will need a bitmap font which contains the emojis before you can print them.

Comment: How would I go about making an emoji bitmap font?

Comment: No idea :) It's going to be a lot more involved than just converting an existing font I think -  here's a [toolset on github](https://github.com/kreativekorp/bitsnpicas) which seems related. Of course you could just get the emojis as images and `blit` or `composite` instead of writing them.